# array some is not working in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to check if current user is present in nested array or not.
this is few part of my sample array which is getting from API:

```
[
    {
        "owner":"abc",
        "_id":"xyz77",
        "comments":[

        ],
        "likes":[
            {
                "_id":"9999",
                "username":"user1"
            },
            {
                "_id":"9998",
                "username":"user2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "owner":"bcd"
    }
]
```

I want to see if **user1** is present in likes array or not. 
if yes then it should give output like this:

```
[
    {
        "owner":"abc",
        "user1":true
    },
    {
        "owner":"bcd",
        "user1":true
    },
    {
        "owner":"def",
        "user1":false
    }
]
```

above result is **likes array** of owner **abc** has **user1** but not present in owner **def**. 
I tried with `array.some` for likes array inside `forEach` of owner array. But not getting proper result. 
help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to create a resulting array which checks if any of the users in the `likes` array of each owner object matches your username:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "owner":"abc",
        "_id":"xyz77",
        "comments":[],
        "likes":[
            {
                "_id":"9999",
                "username":"user1"
            },
            {
                "_id":"9998",
                "username":"user2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "owner":"bcd",
        "_id":"xyz88",
        "comments":[],
        "likes":[
            {
                "_id":"9998",
                "username":"user2"
            },
            {
                "_id":"9997",
                "username":"user3"
            }
        ]
    },
];

const checkUsername = (data, username) => {
  return data.map(e => {
    const x = { owner: e.owner };
    x[username] = e.likes.some(el => el.username === username);
    return x;
  });
};

console.log(checkUsername(data, 'user1'));
console.log(checkUsername(data, 'user2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Similar to @awarrier99 answer, Use destructuring along with `map` and `some`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    owner: "abc",
    _id: "xyz77",
    comments: [],
    likes: [
      {
        _id: "9999",
        username: "user1",
      },
      {
        _id: "9998",
        username: "user2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    owner: "bcd",
  },
];

const update = (arr, user) =>
  data.map(({ likes = [], owner }) => ({
    [user]: likes.some(({ username }) => username === user),
    owner,
  }));
  
console.log(update(data, "user1"));
```